# How to import all search result in to the lead list on LinkedIn sales navigator?

Tags: linkedin-api, lead

Dear Stack Overflow community,

After I have done a search query on Linkedin, I have manually import 600 contacts into lead list (25 every time)

I know you can run the script in the google console.

The code should

click  
Click Save to list
Select the first option from the list

Then we add for-in loop for the pages
7 .

Should I create a web clicker using python, or can I achieve this with a chrome console?